# Kubernetes Dashboard: Token authentication not showing

Tags: kubernetes-dashboard

I'm trying to get the Kubernetes Dashboard Auth token using the following command :

```
kubectl -n kubernetes-dashboard describe secret $(kubectl -n kubernetes-dashboard get secret | grep admin-user | awk '{print $1}')
```

But there is nothing, I followed this [article](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2020/05/21/wsl-docker-kubernetes-on-the-windows-desktop/)
and this is the response without the grep:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPqIz.png)

Comment: If not already done, Try to clean up and retry, and it seems like some accidental operator error. clipboard data pasted?!!??

Comment: Hi thanks, yeah I think it's a data paste prob.

Answer (score 3):

From K8s 1.24, secret created by K8s using serviceaccount token will not created.
You can create serviceaccount token manually

```
kubectl create token SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME -n <namepace>
```

You can set the token duration by setting the duration parameter like

```
kubectl create token myapp --duration 10m
```

This will create the token for 10 minutes, default is 0s.
From the docs:
Default duration is 0s. Duration means Requested lifetime of the issued token. The server may return a token with a longer or shorter lifetime. |
https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#-em-token-em-

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get the token using the command:

```
kubectl -n kubernetes-dashboard get secrets/admin-user-secret -o jsonpath="{.data.token}"
```

Also be aware about LegacyServiceAccountTokenNoAutoGeneration, that's why there are no any token autogeneration no more starting from 1.24
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/110113. So now we need to manually create a service account API token https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-service-account/#manually-create-a-service-account-api-token

Comment: Hi Anton, your information helps.  I can create a token using kubectl create token.  Do you know if it is possible to set an expiration for the token using 'kubectl create token' ?